# Is there a limit on Eddystone beacon scanning period?

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-developer-api, eddystone

I was just curious, I know there is a limit to how many times BeaconManager can scan? I have read that there is [no minimum time length but that there is a maximum time length (5 minutes)](http://2)%20Paypal%20-%20(https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=X2EK4ENXC3ARW)). That thread that I linked states that there is an intention to make the setting fully configurable but I was wanting to know if it had been implemented. Bottom line, can BeaconManager be set to scan longer than 5 minutes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may configure the scan period of the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) for as long as you wish (The default is 1.1 seconds).  The example below sets it to 1 minute:

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(60000l); // 60000 ms = 1 minute
```

The 5 minute limit you read about is probably the `AlarmManager` scan restart interval, which restarts background scanning if the app is inadvertently killed. This is currently fixed at 5 minutes.